# How do i populate an array with the uni codes of characters within a string?

Tags: javascript

I have written a function with the intention of populating an array with uni code characters for each of the letters in a string.

However the result I am being returned is an array of null values.

```js
function rot13(str) {
  var splitString = str.split("");
  var myArray = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < splitString.length; i++) {
    myArray.push(splitString[i].charCodeAt[i]);
  }
  return myArray;
}
console.log(rot13('cats'));
```

Comment: `charCodeAt` is a function.

Comment: `splitString[i].charCodeAt[i]` → `str.charCodeAt(i)`. `charCodeAt` is a function.

Comment: And you don't need `split`.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charCodeAt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`String.prototype.charCodeAt(n)` finds the code of a character in position `n` the string. So instead of splitting the string, just iterate it:

```js
function rot13(str) { 
  var myArray = [];

  for(var i = 0; i < str.length; i++ ) {
    myArray.push(str.charCodeAt(i));
  }
  
  return myArray;
}

console.log(rot13('cats'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Posting this alternative - still using the [function charcodeAt()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charCodeAt)

```js
function rot13(str) { 
  return str.split("").map(function(char) { 
       return char.charCodeAt(); 
  }); // .join("");
}
console.log(rot13("cats"))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 function toChars(x,i){
    x = x.split(""); i = 0;
    while( x[i] ) x[i] = String.charCodeAt( x[i++] );
    return x;
}
```